# Arrow indicator CSS on different tabs

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-shapes

I have noticed that many websites indicate the page or the tab that you are on by using something like this:

[image]

As you can see, there is a little arrow that indicates the page number. How can this be accomplished using pure CSS, or do most sites use a background image of a div that they set the position of using the background-position attribute? It seems this is a fairly common technique, and so the aforementioned seems rather unlikely.

You can see other examples [here](http://dribbble.com/shots/553791-Web-App-UI?list=tags&tag=ui) and [here](http://dribbble.com/shots/553466-Chat?list=tags&tag=ui). It would be nice if solutions worked both horizontally and vertically rotated.

Comment: You can assign two css classes to the `li` (or `div` or whatever element that is the *current* marker); one with the regular styles and the other which you'd set background image or whatever decoration you like.

Comment: maybe this can be helpful: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/

Comment: If you would like to create this through CSS3, a website came to light recently that gives you the CSS you need. Have a look at: [http://cssarrowplease.com/](http://cssarrowplease.com/) If you are looking for a cross browser solution though, it is worth considering background images as per previous answers :)

Comment: Great link! cool demo :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want a pure CSS solution, you can do something like this using the `:after` pseudo-element.

```css
span {
position: relative;
padding: 15px;
color: white;
background: black;
}

.current:after {
content: "";
position: absolute;
bottom: -10px;
left: 18px;
border-width: 15px 15px 0;
border-style: solid;
border-color: black transparent;
}
```

```html
<span class="current">Home</span>
<span>Other</span>
<span>Etc</span>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use css borders to accomplish this too.
If you have the following structure

```
<div class="menu">home</div>
<div class="menu current">about</div>
<div class="menu">Contact</div>
```

Then you can use the following css to to draw a speech bubble or arrow under active menu

```
.current:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;

  width: 0;
  height: 0;

  border: 15px solid;
  border-top-color: #292929;

  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -15px; /* adjust for border width */
}
```

This is a great tutorials explaining the technique http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/css-refreshers-borders/

Answer (score 1):

The arrow is almost always an image, but this is all usually done with CSS classes.

Example in CSS

```
.menu {
Font: whatever;
Background:url("image/parallel.PNG");
}
.current {
Background:URL("image/arrow.PNG");
}
```

And HTML

```
<div class="menu">home</div>
<div class="menu current">about</div>
```

This will give both menu items the font but only one gets the arrow background
you could also put all of these in a container and apply styles to all child elements in the style and then only have to add class="current" to the current page.

View source for this page
http://dynamicinteractions.com/home

Please excuse my phone auto correcting caps all over the code.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, how does it work in examples like this then: http://dribbble.com/shots/553791-Web-App-UI?list=tags&tag=ui

Comment: That's a pop out menu using JavaScript. Can be done with CSS but its much easier with JavaScript.